# How do I find the circumcenter of the triangle using python without external libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I am trying to find the circumcenter of a triangle with python and no external libraries for a geometry calculator that I am making. The thing is I can't use equations such as y=mx+b because the computer thinks that I am trying to define a variable rather than doing algebra.

I have tried a lot of different things such as using sympy and shapely and none of them worked. So far I can find the midpoint and the slope. I am not really sure what to do. Please help. Thank you!

```py
def circumcenter():
    c1 = float(input('What is x of point 1?'))
    c2 = float(input('What is y of point 1?'))
    c3 = float(input('What is x of point 2?'))
    c4 = float(input('What is y of point 2?'))
    c5 = float(input('What is x of point 3?'))
    c6 = float(input('What is y of point 3?'))
    m1 = c1 + c3
    m2 = c2 + c4
    m3 = m1 / 2
    m4 = m2 / 2
    s1a = c3 - c1
    s1b = c4 - c2
    s1c = s1a / s1b
    s2a = c5 - c3
    s2b = c6 - c4
    s2c = s2a / s2b
    s1 = -1 / s1c
    s2 = -1 / s2c
```

There is no output yet because if I print something it will not mean anything other than the slope.

Comment: What a "circumcenter"? You should be able to using the formula "y=mx+b" if you wish, so you were likely doing it wrong—but you haven't shown that attempt...

Comment: @martineau how would I go about using the formula y=mx+b when neither x nor y is defined and a circumcenter is the center of a triangle. I have no idea how I'd go about using the equation y=mx+b so if you have an idea It'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the [Cartesian coordinate equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2) at Wikipedia? They do not use `y = mx + b`--they directly calculate the circumcenter's coordinates using the given point coordinates (you do need to calculate one intermediate value). Is there something about them that you do not understand?

Comment: I didn't state what I said well. I simply meant it's quite possible to _use_ the formula—for example to find the points on a line given its slope and y-intercept. However, after looking up what "cicumcenter" means, I'm not so sure using the formula y=mx+b would be very helpful—so it may be a moot point.

Comment: I'm not clear where you're stuck.  The process of finding the circumcenter is well-documented: it's the intersection of the sides' perpendicular bisectors (and two of the three will define that point).  The process for finding the intersection of two lines is also well documented.  Your code is a series of single-operation steps with cryptic variables and no clear outline to a known solution.

Comment: well i can't really afford a tutor so I turned to stack overflow. I thought I defined my issue but i guess not so ill try to make it more clear what my problem is in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just should apply formulas from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Circumcircle_equations):

> The Cartesian coordinates of the circumcenter are:

[image]

> with

[image]

> 

So your code is:

```
def circumcenter():
    ax = float(input('What is x of point 1?'))
    ay = float(input('What is y of point 1?'))
    bx = float(input('What is x of point 2?'))
    by = float(input('What is y of point 2?'))
    cx = float(input('What is x of point 3?'))
    cy = float(input('What is y of point 3?'))
    d = 2 * (ax * (by - cy) + bx * (cy - ay) + cx * (ay - by))
    ux = ((ax * ax + ay * ay) * (by - cy) + (bx * bx + by * by) * (cy - ay) + (cx * cx + cy * cy) * (ay - by)) / d
    uy = ((ax * ax + ay * ay) * (cx - bx) + (bx * bx + by * by) * (ax - cx) + (cx * cx + cy * cy) * (bx - ax)) / d
    return (ux, uy)
```